# Updating C3 charts on props change with React

Tags: reactjs, c3

I am trying to beautify the update of a C3 chart written as a React component when its data change. The data flows to the component from a parent component via its props.

The solutions I have now "works" but do not seem optimal: when new data comes in, the whole chart is regenerated. I would like to transition to the new state (lines moving rather than whole chart updating in blink). The C3 API seem to have lots of method but I cannot find how to reach the chart.

```
var React = require("react");
var c3 = require("c3");

var ChartDailyRev = React.createClass({
    _renderChart: function (data) {
        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart1',
            data: {
              json: data,
              keys: {
                  x: 'date',
                  value: ['requests', 'revenue']
              },
              type: 'spline',
              types: { 'revenue': 'bar' },
              axes: {
                'requests': 'y',
                'revenue': 'y2'
              }
            },
            axis: {
                x: { type: 'timeseries' },
                y2: { show: true }
            }
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this._renderChart(this.props.data);
    },
    render: function () {
        this._renderChart(this.props.data);
        return (
            <div className="row" id="chart1"></div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = ChartDailyRev;
```

Comment: Did you look at that? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the project's documentation](http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html#api):

> By using APIs, you can update the chart after it's been rendered. ... APIs can be called through the object returned from `generate()`.

So the first thing you need to do is save a reference to the chart when you generate it. It's easy enough to attach it directly to the component:

```javascript
var ChartDailyRev = React.createClass({
    _renderChart: function (data) {
        // save reference to our chart to the instance
        this.chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart1',
            // ...
        });
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        this._renderChart(this.props.data);
    },

    // ...
});
```

Then, you want to update the chart when the props update; React provides a lifecycle hook called `componentWillReceiveProps` that runs when the props have changed.

```javascript
var ChartDailyRev = React.createClass({
    // ...

    componentWillReceiveProps: function (newProps) {
        this.chart.load({
            json: newProps.data
        }); // or whatever API you need
    }
});
```

(Make sure to remove `this._renderChart` from your `render` function.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes a lot of sense!