# C3 chart not rendering in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, c3.js

I want to create a char using c3 in React to, later on, be updated each second.

I am trying to follow the example provided by 
[Updating C3 charts on props change with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018487/updating-c3-charts-on-props-change-with-react), but the first step, which is to create the chart, is not happening.

This is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/227446/

```
import c3 from 'c3';
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Hello extends React.Component {

  renderChart() {
        this.chart = c3.generate({
            bindto:"#chart1",
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                ]
            }
        });
    }



  render() {

    this.renderChart()

    return <div id="chart1"></div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I installed c3 with npm and am importing it in the component.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to include React and ReactDOM.

Comment: Sorry, in my file I have them imported. I wil correct the fiddle

Comment: You need to google about how to bind your functions in React.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I have put some debuggers and found out that the renderChart function is called and runs up to the end, but do not seem to run the c3.generate line. Or it runs and the chart won't appear. Could you explain what you mean with bind my functions? Which should I bind and what may be the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, it looks like the chart is generated before the selector div is even rendered, so the chart has no where to go. Instead of calling `this.renderChart()` in `render()`, you can call it `componentDidMount`. In that case, render will be called on the initial load, your `<div id="chart1"></div>` will be rendered and then `renderChart` will run, adding the SVG to the div.

As for updating the data, you can move the column data itself to state, then call `setState` with some new data and use `componentDidUpdate` to rerender the chart. That might look something like this:

```
class Chart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      column1: ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      column2: ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25],
    };

    this.changeData = this.changeData.bind(this);
  }

  renderChart() {
    c3.generate({
      bindto: "#chart1",
      data: {
        columns: [this.state.column1, this.state.column2],
      },
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderChart();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.renderChart();
  }

  // Changes data to something arbitrary on button click
  changeData() {
    this.setState({
      column1: ['data1', 70, 120, 30, 300, 230, 300],
      column2: ['data2', 100, 120, 50, 140, 150, 80],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="chart1"></div>
        <button onClick={this.changeData}>Change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

React Lifecycle methods are key here. Here's a handy chart linked from the docs: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Comment: Thank you, your version worked. My code was returning an error because I wasn't paying attention to the time the data for the chart was available.
The data comes from a parent character and wasn't available during the DidMount cycle. I transfered the manipulation of the data for WillReceiveProps and the render of the chart to DidUpdate and it kind of worked.